# Reactive form valid property return false when form is disabled

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have this simple form  and used in create and update cases so for create case the user will enter the data and base on validatorsI will get the `form.valid` (true,false).
In update case I just get the data from api and set this value to the form and make the form disable;

```
this.form = fb.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  lastName: ['', Validators.required],
  address: [''],
});
```

so when I make the form disabled the valid value always is `false`;

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.form.patchValue({
      name: 'name',
      lastName: 'Last Name'
    });

    this.form.disable();
  }
```

[**stackblitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-disabled)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is correct. The documentation says:

> A control is valid when its status is VALID.

And the documentation of status says:

> The validation status of the control. There are four possible validation status values:
>
> - VALID: This control has passed all validation checks.
> - INVALID: This control has failed at least one validation check.
> - PENDING: This control is in the midst of conducting a validation check.
> - DISABLED: This control is exempt from validation checks.

Your form is disabled, so it is not valid.

Comment: is there any way to check if the form is valid when it 's disabled ?

Comment: I guess you can enable it, check if it's valid, then disable it again. But why do you care, since it's disabled?

Comment: I use the form.valid property for button disabled  , the same button for create and update so I expected in update case the form has the data so the valid  property is valid so the button is enabled

Comment: I work around this by create a function and check is the form is disabled return true otherwise return form.valid but I thought it 's not right thing to do

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi. I think you want to show the data and a button to "edit", when the we click on edit, you show a form to allow edit the values. So I'll  create a variable (e.g. called "onEdit") and make two forms. two <div *ngIf="onEdit">..</div> and <div *ngIf="!onEdit">..</div> make the trick

Comment: @Eliseo create a variable to check the state will extra pain this just an example, I do create a function an for me it 's no look the right thing to do

Comment: @Eliseo I can check the state of the disable instand of create a variable mthat will be useful

Answer (score 9):

Valid will return false if the form is disabled so I found two way to work around this

instand of check the `valid` property directly I make a function for checking the validity

```
 isFormValid() : boolean { 
    return this.form.disabled ? true : this.form.valid
  }
```

template

```
<button [disabled]="!isFormValid()" (click)="update()">Update</button>
```

another way without create isFormValid function

```
<button [disabled]="!form.valid && form.disabled === false" (click)="update()">Update</button>
```

Comment: Sorry, but how does it check for validity of disabled form? You're returning "true" always when form is disabled, so technically, if I have two required controls with null value, your function will tell me that it's valid.

Comment: when form is disabled it always will return true

Comment: so why this should be a solution for anybody? 
Form could be disabled and not filled.

Answer (score 2):

If not all your fiels of the form are disabled, at this moment, the best workaround to work with reactive forms in cases like this is to mark these fields as readonly. Is not exactly the same but in that way you can have a consistent behaviour.

Related issues:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11447
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/15399

Answer (score 0):

For update case where the input is disabled a workaround to template drive forms to pass validation:

```
<div *ngIf="field.editable; else disabled">
    <ion-input ..
></ion-input> 
</div>
<ng-template #notEditable>
    <p class="disabled">Some text</p>
</ng-template>
```